# How to to input a date within the Gas Day input box through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am using Python and Selenium to read this URL:
http://ips.alliance-pipeline.com/Ips/MainPage.aspx?siteId=4

I use selenium to open it up, click on the plus sign (left hand side) and click "Daily Throughput". A page opens up with "Gas Day" input box, in which I want to input a date. 
If these steps are done manually in regular chrome browser, it works fine, I can input the date and click "Retrieve" and get the data table. But for some reason selenium makes the input box read-only. I have tried removing the "read-only" attribute (see commented out lines), in which case the attribute seems to get removed, but the date is still not entered in the box and data is not retrieved.

Why does selenium make this element read-only and how can I prevent this from happening?

Here is the code:

```
url = 'http://ips.alliance-pipeline.com/Ips/MainPage.aspx?siteId=4'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_id('treeviewn0').click() # click on "Capacity" heading
browser.find_element_by_id('treeviewt1').click() # click on "Daily Throughput" heading
time.sleep(2)
# browser.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("igte_EditInContainer")[0].removeAttribute("readonly")')
d = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=5)
d_str = d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
date_box = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MainContent_dtJobSchedForGrid"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/input')
# print(date_box.get_attribute('readonly'))
date_box.send_keys(d_str + '\n')
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_id('MainContent_btnRetrieveJobSchedForGrid').click() # click the Retrieve button
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Can you post the error you get? It might be several reasons why it fails.

Comment: Selenium is just using your regular browser, so I don't see how it could be causing this problem.  Instead, there must be some step that you perform manually that you're not replicating in the script.  Perhaps it's a step that you're not even aware you're doing, like hovering over an element?

Comment: @niklas I don't get an error, it just doesn't enter the date into the input, and so the data table doesn't come up when the "Retrieve" button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

To send a *date* as a *character sequence* to the **Gas Day** field you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  browser.get("http://ips.alliance-pipeline.com/Ips/MainPage.aspx?siteId=4")
  browser.find_element_by_id('treeviewn0').click() # click on "Capacity" heading
  browser.find_element_by_id('treeviewt1').click() # click on "Daily Throughput" heading
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.igte_EditInContainer"))).send_keys("10/04/2018")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: date]